# Hibernate Criteria: Add restrictions to Criteria and DetachedCriteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

Currently our queries add a variety of Restrictions to ensure the results are considered active or live. These Restrictions are used in several places/queries so a method was setup similar to

```
 public Criteria addStandardCriteria(Criteria criteria, ...) {
      // Add restrictions, create aliases based on parameters
      //     and other non-trivial logic
     criteria.add(...);
     return criteria;
 }
```

This has worked fine so far, but now this standard criteria needs to be added to a subquery using DetachedCriteria. Is there a way to modify this method to accept Criteria or DetachedCriteria or a Better way to add restrictions?

Comment: Can you give me a little more information?  Criteria and DetachedCriteria both have createCriteria() methods on them so you could create a sub criteria and then pass that into this method.  I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I don't think since the aren't the same and don't extend the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the queries so this was no longer an issue, but before that I created this class which seemed to work but your mileage may vary:

```
 public class CriteriaContainer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Criteria criteria = null;
    private DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = null;

    public CriteriaContainer(Criteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
        this.detachedCriteria = null;
    }

    public CriteriaContainer(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria) {
        this.detachedCriteria = detachedCriteria;
        this.criteria = null;
    }

    /**
     * @param eq
     * @return 
     */
    public CriteriaContainer add(final Criterion eq) {
        if (criteria != null) {
            criteria.add(eq);
        } else if (detachedCriteria != null) {
            detachedCriteria.add(eq);
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the criteria
     */
    public Criteria getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }

    /**
     * @return the detachedCriteria
     */
    public DetachedCriteria getDetachedCriteria() {
        return detachedCriteria;
    }

    /**
     * @param associationPath
     * @param alias
     * @return 
     */
    public CriteriaContainer createAlias(final String associationPath, final String alias) {
        if (criteria != null) {
            criteria.createAlias(associationPath, alias);
        } else if (detachedCriteria != null) {
            detachedCriteria.createAlias(associationPath, alias);
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param distinctRootEntity
     * @return 
     */
    public CriteriaContainer setResultTransformer(final ResultTransformer transformer) {
        if (criteria != null) {
            criteria.setResultTransformer(transformer);
        } else if (detachedCriteria != null) {
            detachedCriteria.setResultTransformer(transformer);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

criteria = addBasicCriteria(new CriteriaContainer(criteria), ...).getCriteria()
detachedCriteria = addBasicCriteria(new CriteriaContainer(detachedCriteria), ...).getDetachedCriteria()
```